# Microsoft Visio missing shape templates

Tags: microsoft-visio, diagrams, drawing, shapes

I'm using MS Visio 2003 Standard.  When I first was using it 3 years ago, it would let you search a database of thousands of ready-made templates, which I think Microsoft hosted at their own website.  Several months ago, these templates were no longer available.  I'm looking for some kind of replacement for common computer architecture and digital circuits, as well as user interface mock-ups.  Does anybody know where I can find an assortment of these 'shapes'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest site I could find for computer architecture is

http://visiotoolbox.com/2010/templates.aspx

Mostly the templates relate to flowcharts and specialized nodes on networks.